# Wireless connectivity cuts out after 20 mins when plugged into mains

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-vista

Can someone help me.

I'm running Windows Vista on a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo PI 2530 laptop.

Ever since I've had my laptop, 6 years now I've had an issue whereby the Wireless connectivity cuts out after about 25 minutes when I have my laptop plugged into the mains. If it's running off the battery then the connectivity is fine. I would be grateful if someone could advise on why this is happening and what the solution might be.

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading this fixed this issue for someone.

Unistall drivers and then reinstall them.

Then go to: Power Options->Balanced ->Change power plan -> Change advanced power setting -> Wireless Adapter Setting -> Power Saving Mode ...and make sure these settings are selected-> On Battery: Max. Performance; Plugged in: Maximum Performance.

If this doesn't work I would search for a different version of your wireless driver.